# Howto setup IDA Pro Dalvik Debugger Process Options to debug APK on a real device

Tags: ida, dalvik

I had some fun using IDA Pro Dalvik Debugger in the past using AVD emulator. 
However I stumbled upon a APK that somehow does not run well inside AVD. APK runs fine on a real device so I am trying to use IDA Pro dalvik debugger to debug the APK on a real device.

The problem is, when using AVD all I had to setup was packagename and activity name in the `Debugger Setup -> Set specific options` and debugger worked well but trying on a real device keep fails with message like `ADB error: listener 'tcp:239166' not found` or `IDA started the application but unable to connect ..` message.

I tried `adb forward` on a port Dalvik debugger is using but no progress :(

Can anyone provide help? Thanks in advance.

Comment: `ADB request:
0000: 30 30 31 32                                     "0012"
ADB request:
0000: 68 6F 73 74 3A 74 72 61 6E 73 70 6F 72 74 2D 61 "host:transport-a"
0010: 6E 79                                           "ny"
ADB answer:
0000: 4F 4B 41 59                                     "OKAY"
ADB request:
0000: 30 30 30 34                                     "0004"
ADB request:
0000: 6A 64 77 70                                     "jdwp"
ADB answer:
0000: 4F 4B 41 59                                     "OKAY"
ADB answer:` This repeats in the IDA debug msg

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Setting the target app to `debuggable` in the android manifest and repackaging the apk has done the job. I didn't know that AVD automatically sets the APK to debuggable.

Comment: You could also solve this problem once and forever by modifying Android image so that any apk is considered debuggable. Something along these lines: https://reverseengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/13194/howto-setup-ida-pro-dalvik-debugger-process-options-to-debug-apk-on-a-real-devic

Comment: Thanks for the comment. But the link points to this page : )

Comment: Oops I meant this  http://www.surrendercontrol.com/2016/03/fiddling-with-nexus-4-boot-image.html

Comment: how do you set debuggable on the APK ? using an old Apktool ? cause the latest Apktool is not supporting d switch.

Comment: my version supports d switch. I didn't know latest version does not